# Como enviar datos en una cadena mediante ajax?

Tags: php, jquery

Necesito su ayuda señores. Verán quiero mandar el valor de 3 variables las cuales vienen de varios campos de un formulario,excepto una la cual la paso a javascript desde PHP. Si se preguntan si esa variables cargan los valores,digo que si.Ya probé eso,mediante "alert();"

El problema esta en que solo me registra la primera de ellas en la BD,las demás no hacen nada,no aparecen.

**JQUERY**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

  $('#btnGL').click(function(){

  var id_post = $('#bookId').val();//Obtener valor del campo con el ID del post
  var id_usuario = <?php echo $id_user ?>;//Obtener ID del usuario que hizo el post
  var obtenerBallon = $('#ageOutputId').val();//Obtener valor del campo cantidad de ballons

 alert(id_usuario);
 alert(id_post);

 var datos = 'idPost='+ id_post + 'idUsuario='+ id_usuario + 'puntos='+ 
 obtenerBallon;

 $.ajax({

 type:'POST',
 url:'VotosGL.php',
 data:datos,
 success:function(result){
 alert(result);
 }

});

});

});

</script>
```

**PHP** VotosGL.php

```
  <?php 

include('conexion.php');

$id_post = $_POST['idPost'];
$id_usuario = $_POST['idUsuario'];
$puntos = $_POST['puntos'];

$insert =  mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO posts_votos   
(id_post,id_usuario,puntos) VALUES('$id_post','$id_usuario','$puntos')");

 ?>
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la variable que se inserta en la BD?

Comment: @Error404 id_post.

Comment: ¿De que tipo son las variables? Los `id` suelen ser enteros y tu se los pasas como String. Comprueba a ver si es por eso.

Comment: @Error404 Y cual código lo cambio?En el Jquery?

Comment: Me refiero. Mira a ver en la BD que tipo de datos tienen esos campos, los tres que quieres introducir. Si son enteros, varchar, etc...

Comment: @Error404  Todos son INT

Comment: Entonces pon en tu consulta `VALUES($id_post, $id_usuario, $puntos)`

Comment: @Error404 Ahora no me inserta nada,Y lanza error,diciendo que los campos no están definidos "id_usuario" y "puntos" del php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trata de enviar los datos asi, puede ser porque les falta el &

```
var datos = 'idPost='+ id_post + '&idUsuario='+ id_usuario + '&puntos='+ 
 obtenerBallon;
```

En caso de que tampoco funcione envialos como un objeto

```
var datos = {
  idPost: id_post,
  idUsuario: id_usuario,
  puntos: obtenerBallon
}

$.ajax({

  type:'POST',
  url:'VotosGL.php',
  data:datos,
  success:function(result){
  alert(result);
 }
});
```

Comment: Me funciono la parte usando "&"

Comment: Me podrías decir cual es la funcion de usar &?

Comment: Me alegra poder haberte ayudado.

Comment: con ? le estamos diciendo que desde ese momento recibira los datos por marametro get y usar & despues de cada parametro es para decirle, se envia este datto y este otro dato y este otro.

`?dato1=1&datos2=2`

pero como en tu caso es por metodo post no se agrega el ? y solo se envia los datos con &.

Comment: ok.Muchismas gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

También lo puedes usar así, directo sin armar un arreglo

```
var id_post = $('#bookId').val();
var id_usuario = <?php echo $id_user ?>;
var obtenerBallon = $('#ageOutputId').val();

$.ajax({
  type:'POST',
  url:'VotosGL.php',
  data:{id_post:id_post,id_usuario:id_usuario,obtenerBallon:obtenerBallon},
  success:function(result)
  {
    alert(result);
  }
});
```

Y en PHP recuperarías los datos de la siguiente forma:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST["id_post"])){$id_post = $_REQUEST["id_post"];}else{$id_post = "";}
if(isset($_REQUEST["id_usuario"])){$id_usuario = $_REQUEST["id_usuario"];}else{$id_usuario= "";}
if(isset($_REQUEST["obtenerBallon"])){$obtenerBallon= $_REQUEST["obtenerBallon"];}else{$obtenerBallon= "";}
```